# jQuery Mobile: RequireJS and loading initial page

Tags: jquery-mobile, requirejs

So I'm specifically trying to use RequireJS and jQuery Mobile. I'd like to load the intial page from inside the application rather than just putting it directly on index.html because I'll need to add logic later as to which page to load first.

It doesn't give me any errors and jquerymobile is loaded, but the page isn't loaded into the DOM. Any thoughts or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

**main.js**

```
require.config({
        baseUrl: 'js/app',

        paths: {
            jquery: '../vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min',
            jquerymobile: '../vendor/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min'
        },

        shim: {
            jquerymobile: {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }

    });

    require(['jquerymobile'], function() {

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.mobile.pageContainer = $('#container');
            $.mobile.loadPage('view/home.html', { transition: 'slideup' });
        });

    });
```

**view/home.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">Home</div>
    <div data-role="content">Content</div>
    <div data-role="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not a require expert, but `.ready` isn't recommended to be used in JQM. Replace it with `.on('pageinit', function` and `changePage` instead of `loadPage`.

Comment: I was reading about that. I've played around with both combination of ready and pageinit, as well as changePage and loadPage. Using ready will actually link to the page, but doesn't display the content.

Comment: According to http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/faq/dom-ready-not-working.html I should be able to use the ready event for the first page.

Comment: Are you sure the function is working? Try adding an alert or a console.log to make sure that the function is working.

Comment: Yes, I put a console log after my mobile page load and it's running.

Comment: Hmmm..try `$('body').load('home.html');` and then `$('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');`.